# Java, hiding methods of super super class

Tags: java

I am porting some OpenGL Nvidia C samples to jogl and I have the following (`init` is one of the abstract methods required by `GLEventListener`:

```
public abstract class NvAppBase implements GLEventListener {
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        initRendering(gl4);
    }
    public void initRendering(GL4 gl4) {
    }
}

public abstract class NvSampleApp extends NvAppBase {
    @Override
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        baseInitRendering(gl4);
    }
    protected void baseInitRendering(GL4 gl4) {
        initRendering(gl4);
    }
    @Override
    public void initRendering(GL4 gl4) {
    }
}
public class BindlessApp extends NvSampleApp{    
    @Override
    public void initRendering(GL4 gl4) {    
    }
}
```

Given that:

- `NvAppBase` is not used at all, all the samples (such as `BindlessApp`) always extend `NvSampleApp`
- I'd like the class extending `NvSampleApp` to being able to see (and overwrite)  only the `initRendering` and not also the `init`

Is there a better way than just having `NvSampleApp` simply as a variable inside `BindlessApp`, like this for example?

```
public class BindlessApp {    
    private NvSampleApp sampleApp;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `final`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keyword `final` for this purpose.

[Writing Final Classes and Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html) on Oracle java tutorial.

> You can declare some or all of a class's methods final. You use the
>   final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method
>   cannot be overridden by subclasses. The Object class does this—a
>   number of its methods are final.

Comment: Yep, right, it works perfectly... thanks man, I can accept it in 3m

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way than just having NvSampleApp simply as a
>   variable inside BindlessApp, like this for example?

Although it seems like more work, **encapsulation** is a great tool to help isolate parts of your code an decrease coupling.

I think in your case it might even be the better solution :)

See for more detail this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301036/461499

Comment: I'd like to go with the Ferrybig's answer, but thanks anyway for the interesting link